# landscape rotating wrong page in

Tags: landscape, pdflscape

Consider the following MWE. I would like a large figure in my text to have a landscape orientation in the pdfviewer so I am using pdflscape. I found that I have to use the `revtex4` option instead of the standard `revtex4-1` that is used in the `emlateapj class`, but still the landscape is not working correctly.

The page with the figure is not rotated, the page before is. If I put the landscape in and `\afterpage` environment, than nothing is rotated anymore... What is happening here and more importantly, how can I solve it? It is driving me nuts that it takes me so long on such a simple problem.

```
\documentclass[revtex4]{emulateapj}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Dummy Title}
\author{someone and someone}

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum
\end{abstract}

\keywords{key1,key2}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\lipsum
\lipsum
%\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{testFig.png}
  \captionof{figure}{some caption} 
\end{landscape}
%}
\section{Conclusions}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the documentclass that you have chosen, the problem resolves if you use article class. I don't know however why the chosen documentclass has that behaviour. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: yes it is very specific for this documentclass, it has some other quirks too and a lot of incompatibilities with other packages but I'm stuck with this so I hope someone has a clue